# New install of ARMA 3 freezing on startup

Tags: technical-issues, arma-3

I just bought ARMA 3 yesterday and I am really sad that it will not work.
I have tried re installing it, Deleting arma.exe and checking integrity, and disabling mods but so far, nothing has worked. I can provide you with anything you need such as logs.

Specs:

Processor Type  AMD A10-6700
Processor Speed 3.7 GHz
RAM 8 GB (1600 MHz DDR3)
Hard Drive Capacity 1 TB
Hard Drive Speed (Revolutions Per Minute)   7200 RPM
Pre-loaded Operating System Windows 8.1 64-Bit
Graphics Card AMD Radeon R7 Series / HD 9000 Series

Log: http://pastebin.com/kQv7TC9A

Comment: Since you offer: logs please. Also OS, computer hardware specs, etc.

Comment: Edit Made******

Comment: I don't have a joystick and the sound drivers seem to be fine :(

Comment: Has it ever worked?  Where'd you buy it from?

Comment: I bought it off steam. I have to admit, I did pirate it from nosteam just to try before I buy. It worked without steam but the one I bought does not work :(

Comment: That might be critical information; have you deleted the pirated copy?  It might be interfering with the legit version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Conflicting Software.
The software is called Raptr.